# Is there a canonical book on Monodroid?

Tags: books, android, mono, monodroid

So far I have been living of standard Android books and mainly blogs for Monodroid, but I'm trying to find a definitive resource about the topic and not having any luck.

Is there a book out there that's the de-facto standard for describing best practices, design methodologies, and other helpful information on Monodroid? What makes that book special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've looked over the documentation and tutorials on the Mono for Android site. Outside that, the only book currently in the pipeline that I found is [Professional Android Programming with Mono for Android and .NET/C#](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118026438).